# Create Keys in Azure Key Vault by using API

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I was created azure key vault through in the specified subscription. Followed this article,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvaultpreview/vaults/createorupdate#examples

And when the api called, azure vault created successfully. Now I also need to create a key for the created  Key vault. Is it possible to create the key when the azure key vault creation?

Comment: You'll need to use the Key Vault API, Azure's ARM API can only create the vault.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to create the key at the time of azure key vault creation (not call separate api )?

Comment: No, you will have to make a separate call, though it can be automated as well.

Comment: Is need to set any permission in azure Key-vault for creating new key?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create an access policy in the key vault when you create it that allows your script to create keys :)

Comment: "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "objectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "encrypt",
            "decrypt",
            "wrapKey",
            "unwrapKey",
            "sign",
            "verify",
            "get",
            "list",
            "create",
            "update",
            "import",
            "delete",
            "backup",
            "restore",
            "recover",
            "purge"
          ], -

Comment: already created key vault with this access policies, but I get forbidden error.

Comment: The operation "List" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy.- this message shown in Keys section even after set permissions

Comment: Have you given your user access too? :)

Comment: Out of interest do you especially need to use the REST API directly? The SDKs / ARM templates provide this feature for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create the key when the azure key vault creation?

As juunas said, you need to make a separate call to achieve what you want.

I test it with the following code, it works correctly on my side. The resourceUri is `https://vault.azure.net`. For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731941/getting-unathorized-when-trying-to-get-a-secret-from-azure-key-vault/46766922#46766922).

In `Key vault` channel, you need to `Add policies` to your registered application or user. And in `Access Control` you need to `add permission` to your registered application or user.

[image]
[image]

```
var appId = "0000000000000000000000000000000";
var secretKey = "******************************************";
var tenantId = "0000000000000000000000000000000";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var requestURl = "https://xxxxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/xxxx/create?api-version=2016-10-01";
    string body = "{\"kty\": \"RSA\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is possible use identity ? and with out auth by coding?