# No reply address is registered for the application when there is one configured

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm making a WPF application and it must get a key from Azure Key Vault, but I've always this error:

> AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.
>
> [image]

This is my code I use:

```
public class KeyProvider
{
    public string BaseUrl => "https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net";
    public Uri RedirectUri => new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
    public KeyVaultClient KeyVaultClient { get; private set; }

    public KeyProvider()
    {
        KeyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(GetAccessToken);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string key)
    {
        SecretBundle secret = await KeyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(BaseUrl, key);
        return secret.Value;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string azureTenantId, string clientId, string redirectUri)
    {
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(azureTenantId);
        AuthenticationResult tokenResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientId, RedirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession));

        return tokenResult.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

When I debug `GetAccessToken`, I see that `redirectUri` *(the argument from the method)* is an empty string.

This is my configuration in the Azure portal.

[image]

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the redirect uri is http. But in your application, it is https.  Please try to set them as the same one.

**Update:**

Permissions:

[image]

Platform:

[image]

Add access policy for the user in Key Vault.

[image]

Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static string clientId = "d4c9b2ed-****-****-****-30a787f7c928";
    public static string redirectUri = "https://localhost/";
    public static string baseUrl = "https://jackkv.vault.azure.net/";

    public static async Task<string> AuthenticationCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var result = await new AuthenticationContext(authority).AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession));
        return result.AccessToken;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.ReadLine();

        KeyVaultClient kvc = new KeyVaultClient(AuthenticationCallback);
        var secret = kvc.GetSecretAsync(baseUrl, "testSecret").Result;

        Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug. I've based me on [a probably outdated answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731941/getting-unathorized-when-trying-to-get-a-secret-from-azure-key-vault/46766922#46766922). This is my code now:

```
public string ClientID => "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef";

// skipped some lines...

private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string redirectUri)
{
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    AuthenticationResult tokenResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, ClientID, RedirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession));

    return tokenResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having trouble, I had this issue when trying to set up Active Directory login at work. I confirmed with my IT department many times that the redirectURI was configured correctly in Azure App Services

Turns out we needed to add login.microsoft.com to the allowed CORS list. After allowing that site the application worked as expected